# Change height of rows in Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have the following body of html:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid h-100 border">
        <div class="row h-50">
            <div class="col-sm-12 bg-danger">Row1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row h-50">
            <div class="col-sm-12 bg-primary">Row2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to change the heights of the 2 rows, but always having them both fill the container. As it is they both take up half of the screen. However if I change the heights to say 20 and 80, the rows just revert to 2 tiny rows at the top of the screen. The only other heights that work are 100 and 100 which just makes 2 full screen rows which is not what I want either.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have to set html and body to 100% height.

Then you can use predefined bootstrap classes, like `h-50` or `h-75` to fill the container as you desire - that is no such class like `h-80`, as you can [check here.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/)

However, if you want specific heights you can simply create custom classes, like so:

```
.h-80 {
    height: 80%;
}

.h-20 {
    height: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

#### Use `flex-grow-1`

Use these clasees on `div.container-fluid`

1. d-flex - to make it flex
2. flex-column  - to change its direction to column
3. h-100  - to make its height 100%.

Should you want  that both of the `rows` fill the container equally, use `flex-grow-1` on each one of them.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container h-100 d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="row flex-grow-1 bg-danger"></div>
  <div class="row flex-grow-1 bg-primary"></div>
</div>
```

Rows fills 50% of container

---

Otherwise, use `flex-grow-1` on one of them and control hieght of the second one.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container h-100 d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="row h-25 bg-danger"></div>
  <div class="row flex-grow-1 bg-primary"></div>
</div>
```

The first row fills 25% of the container and the second one the rest of available space.

---

*All of the parents of the container need to have `100%` height.*